# How can I match file name and a variable in a YAML file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, yaml

I am new to shell scripting. What I exactly want to do is this: There is a YAML file and there are different variables in that file, I need to match a particular variable name with a directory name that exists in another location.

Example YAML:

```yaml
input_dir: open_dir/
model: '6ZahsvvRead45F'
solution_name: 6ZahsvvRead45Fs44F
```

With this `solution_name` variable, I have another folder two directories back there a folder exists with the same name as the variable `6ZahsvvRead45Fs44F`. How can I look for this `6ZahsvvRead45Fs44F` in YAML and match it with this folder name which is two directories back? Should I use `grep`, `awk` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use grep, awk or something else?

Something else - yaml aware tool such as `yq`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! solution_name="$(yq -er .solution_name file.yaml)"
then
    printf "Failed to extract solution_name\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

find ../.. -type d -name "$solution_name"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I need to match the value of solution_name which has to be same folder name exist in another location can you please guide me?. Because ls -ld ../../"$solution_name" this command will only take me to that location. I tried storing it into a variable but how can I compare them? Can I use  ``` gdo = yq -er $var "solution_name"
    
#     kdo = ls -ld ../foldername/"$config"
#     if [ $gdo -eq $kdo ]```Thanks in advance

Comment: `ls` will not take you anywhere, it's not `cd`. I don't understand what do you mean by _match_ - you want to find it?

Comment: Matching means the value example: solution_name : efiubwi12uh. So the value here is efiubwi12uh and in other directory we need to find a folder of the same name. So what I meant to say it the value should match with the folder name. Thanks

Comment: @Roger: see edited answer, is this what you want?